# Как правильно пишутся команды?

Tags: орфография

1. На счет раз (выделять как-нибудь или нет?)
2. Команда "Встать"
3. Принять стойку: ближняя нога на колено... (тире или ничего?)

Comment: Уточнение : ближняя нога на колено?? Своя ближняя нога...

Comment: видимо, это из Камасутры...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.На счет "раз"

2.Команда "Встать!"

3.Принять стойку: ближняя нога - на колено...  Можно и ничего не ставить, это эллиптическое предложение с пропуском сказуемого, чаще там ставится тире,но если паузу при произнесении не делаете - тире не нужно. Однако команда чётче звучит с паузой, я бы поставила тире.

Answer (score 1):

> Принять стойку: ближняя нога на колено...

Эта "команда" никак не пишется. Её и произносить-то страшно. О чем вообще речь?
Если это что-то из области служебной кинологии, то скорее всего это две команды "Принять стойку!" и "Нога - на колено!". Больше ничего в "ближнюю голову" не приходит. Тогда и писать надо в две фразы. Тире - по желанию.

Остальное - у Людмилы.

Comment: Меня здесь не было...

Comment: Ой, простите, машинально набрал другой ник.

Comment: Возможно, это стойка для прицеливания во время стрельбы. Я почему-то это представила. А ближняя или дальняя нога от чего-то, это уже становится понятным на местности. Нужно знать ситуацию, а если не знаем, зачем фантазировать... Нас же спросили о грамотности, остальное - дело автора.

Comment: Стрельба с колена - это мне вполне понятно, фантазировать не надо. 
Военные сейчас её редко практикуют, но у спортсменов - вполне.
Но вот "ближняя нога" - это что-то марсианское. К чему "ближняя"?   
Я почему про кинологов подумал: ближняя нога - это та, с какой стороны собака (обычно - справа). И стойка проводника на одном колене там практикуется. Вспомните хотя бы скульптуры "пограничник с собакой", числом уступавшие только "девушке с веслом".  
А насчет авторского пояснения -так я только за.